# Cannot join tables in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 simple tables in a sqlite file:
assets: {id, symbol, name} - all text fields
ratings: {symbol, rating} - all text fields

I'm trying to get a query that will get {id, symbol, name, rating}, but I must be missing something, because rating always comes back as `null`.

Things I tried:

1. Adding 2 associations (`hasOne` and `belongsTo`)
2. Adding `references` to the foreign key in the ratings model
3. Adding `targetKey` field name to the association

Here's my code: schemas, models, association, and query:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:./stocks.sqlite3', {
  operatorsAliases: false,
  logging: false
});

const stocksSchema = {
  id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false},
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
  symbol: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
};

const stocksModel = sequelize.define('stock', stocksSchema, {
  tableName: 'stocks',
  timestamps: false
});

const ratingsSchema = {
  symbol: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, references: {model: stocksModel, key: 'symbol'}},
  rating: {type: Sequelize.STRING(2), allowNull: false}
};

const ratingsModel = sequelize.define('rating', ratingsSchema, {
  tableName: 'ratings',
  timestamps: false
});

//association
stocksModel.hasOne(ratingsModel, {foreignKey: 'symbol'});

//query
const getById = async (id) => {
    try {
      return await stocksModel.findOne({
        where: {id: id},
        include:[{model: ratingsModel}]})
      .then(result => result ? result.dataValues : Promise.reject('not found'));
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

**Update:**
per request, turned on logging, got the following SQL:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `stocks`.`id`, `stocks`.`name`, `stocks`.`symbol`, `rating`.`symbol` AS `rating.symbol`, `rating`.`rating` AS `rating.rating` FROM `stocks` AS `stocks` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ratings` AS `rating` ON `stocks`.`id` = `rating`.`symbol` WHERE `stocks`.`id` = 'XYZ';
```

The result:

```
dataValues: {
  id: 'XYZ',
  name: 'XYZStock',
  symbol: 'xyz',
  rating: null
}
```

A row with `symbol = 'xyz'` exists in both tables.

Comment: Will you please post the generated query and the result also ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi added

Comment: @VivekDoshi looking at the query, seems like it's joining on the wrong field name: `...ON 'stocks'.'id' = 'rating'.'symbol'` instead of `ON 'stocks'.'symbol' = 'rating'.'symbol'`. How do I fix that in Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with association ,

Add this line also :

```
ratingsModel.belongsTo(stocksModel, {foreignKey: 'symbol' , targetKey : 'symbol' });
```

Comment: Doesn't help. It still tries to join stocks.id on ratings.symbol :(
So now I have both associations `stocks.hasOne(ratings...)` and ratings.belongsTo(stocks...)` and it still doesn't work. Can it have something to do with the actual tables?